# Issues with setting state with UsePosition Hook

Tags: reactjs

When setting state using the UsePosition hook inside UseEffect for when the position updates, the state doesn't reflect the coordinates inside UsePosition.

```
 const {latitude, longitude, error, timestamp, accuracy} = 
   usePosition(true, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
const [coords, setCoords] = useState({
    lat: null,
    long: null
});

useEffect(() => {       
    setCoords({lat: latitude, long: longitude});              
    console.log(coords.lat + " " + coords.long);  
    console.log(latitude + " " + longitude):
},[latitude, longitude]);
```

console keeps printing undefined undefined for coords.lat and long but the actual coordinates for latitude and longitude. Im basically trying to set an initial viewport using the initial coordinates so the map (leaftlet-open maps) isn't set to a fixed position in my viewport state (only for the start, I have it working so when the map is moved the viewport updates to reflect the changes in zoom and centre). Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `setState` in Class components, updater function that `useState` returns is also asynchronous. That means that the changes that you make to your state will not instantly reflect in your state.
One possible solution of this problem could be to add another `useEffect` hook that is run when `coords` change.

```
const {latitude, longitude, error, timestamp, accuracy} = 
usePosition(true, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
const [coords, setCoords] = useState({
  lat: null,
  long: null
});

useEffect(() => {       
  setCoords({lat: latitude, long: longitude});
},[latitude, longitude]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(coords) // changes will reflect in your state here
}, [coords]);
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I only a month or so in so just figuring all this stuff out.